# Get likes from twitter in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I can't get likes and other basic information.
I use `omniauth-twitter` gem.

This is my `home_controller.rb`

```
if session[:twitter_token].present?
      twitter_token = current_user.social_medias.find_by_media_type("twitter").token
      client = Twitter::Streaming::Client.new do |config|
        config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
        config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
        config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
        config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
      end
      p 'twitter'
      p client
    end
```

I got this error in my console..

```
NameError (uninitialized constant HomeController::Twitter):
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:277:in `edit_profile'
```

Comment: try to prepend `Twitter` namespace with `::`, i.e. `::Twitter::Streaming::Client`

Comment: Twitter is not loaded. Add `require 'twitter'` to top of file

Comment: @Dinesh I think gem is required by including it in Gemfile.

Comment: hi guys i tried both..but still not working

Comment: show the error when you are using `::Twitter::Streaming::Client`

Comment: @Aleksey i think you are right...I didn't required twitter gem.. i need to add gem 'twitter'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you must required twitter gem also..

```
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'twitter'
```

And i got response like this in my console..

```
#<Twitter::Streaming::Client:0xb2ed008c @consumer_key="OxVFLj95hQXTLmln1bBfNPYqJ", @consumer_secret="c0JqZs5jUc6G0M8UTWA4AqErxZV7ztKMQ5iwR0llk5M7E7xXiq", @access_token="786800200815751168-rvqqfX8kRPgx2LiNflHXazyPGrwQDry", @access_token_secret="09ZK5WKwWB1ECvOJwOslGtJBnHZHw32aJmk5PSy6QZVOD", @connection=#<Twitter::Streaming::Connection:0xb7b7fcc @tcp_socket_class=TCPSocket, @ssl_socket_class=OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket>>
```

and this is get basic information from twitter(i.e, likes, followers, followings)

```
if session[:twitter_token].present?
      twitter_token = current_user.social_medias.find_by_media_type("twitter").token
      @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
        config.consumer_key        = "consumer_key"
        config.consumer_secret     = "consumer_secret"
        config.access_token        = "access_token"
        config.access_token_secret = "access_token_secret"
      end
      p 'twitter'
      p @client
      p 'followers'
      @twitter_followers = @client.followers.count
      p @followers = @client.followers.count
      p 'following'
      p @twitter_following = @client.friends.count
    end
```

Thanks all :) :)

Comment: @Aleksey actually i solve that error and this is i need..now i want another issue..

Comment: Then post another question but find similiar questions first.

Comment: ok i can understand you...but i have limited to ask question.this is my today's last question..